# joining sentences

Tags: sentence-construction, mathematics

I know this is a specific question, but how can I combine sentence 1 and sentence 2? I simply used 'commas' to join them. Is this the correct way to do this?

> 1. Testing of previously fixed edge and currently fixed edge is done in order to maintain     the correct alignment of the boundary
>      segments.
> 2. previously fixed edge and currently fixed edge are relevant to the two successive corners     but associated with a same polygon.

after joining

> Testing of previously fixed edge and currently fixed edge, relevant to
>   the two successive corners but associated with a same polygon, is done
>   in order to maintain the correct alignment of the boundary segments.

Can you please help me combine these 2 sentences into one?

Comment: This looks like Off Topic proofreading to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Sentence 1 and Sentence 2 are both full sentences in their own right, but you think a full stop (i.e., a period) will make the reading too choppy, then you should use a semicolon.

As is stated at the [Purdue OWL](http://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/566/01/):

> Use a semicolon to join 2 independent clauses when the second clause restates the first or when the two clauses are of equal emphasis.

Comment: thanks, that mean if it would be like this will it be meaningful? :- Testing of previously fixed edge and currently fixed edge is done in order to maintain the correct alignment of the boundary segments; the edges referring to the two successive corners but associated with a same polygon.

Comment: @niro: The language is rather technical, so it's hard for me to know for sure, but here's my best shot: _Testing of the previously fixed edge and the currently fixed edge is done to maintain the correct alignment of the boundary segments; these edges refer to two successive corners associated with a same polygon._

Answer (score 0):

Your join is fine grammatically, but there is the potential for ambiguity in the meaning.

> Testing of previously fixed edge and currently fixed edge, relevant to the two successive corners  ...

could suggest that *the testing* is what is relevant, not simply the edges themselves.

This is not necessarily wrong as reading the rest of the text may provide the context necessary to remove the ambiguity.  Similarly, if the target audience are aware of fixed edge properties, there may not be any ambiguity in the statement as they wouldn't draw the inference that the testing and not the edges themselves were relevant.

It's all context.